# SQL Not Exists include null value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two SQL Server tables :

Table 1

```
Id name   description     version
----------------------------------
1  Book1  Book 1 Title    v1
2  Book2  Book 2 Title    v2
3  Book3  Book 3 Title    NULL
4  Book5  Book 5 Title    v3
```

Table 2

```
Id name   description     version
----------------------------------
1  Book1  Book 1 Title    v1
2  Book2  Book 2 Title    v2
3  Book3  Book 3 Title    NULL
4  Book4  Book 4 Title    NULL
5  Book5  Book 5 Title    NULL
```

I want to select all data from table 2 that doesn't exist in table 1 so I can 
insert them into another table.

Here's the SQL query :

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.description, t2.version
FROM Table2 AS t2
WHERE  
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT t1.name, t1.description, t1.version 
                FROM Table1 as t1 
                WHERE t2.name = t1.name 
                  AND t2.description = t1.description  
                  AND t2.version = t1.version)
```

The result expected is this :

```
Id name   description     version
-----------------------------------
4  Book4  Book 4 Title    NULL
5  Book5  Book 5 Title    NULL
```

But I'm getting this instead:

```
Id name   description     version
---------------------------------
3  Book3  Book 3 Title    NULL
4  Book4  Book 4 Title    NULL
```

Why the null value are not evaluated in my `NOT EXIST` statement and are displayed?

Comment: NULL value when compare with anything will return `FALSE`. You will need to use `INSULL()` to handle

Comment: because `NULL = NULL` is falsy. Having a primary key is easier. Also check [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement.

Comment: Take a look at SQL Server's MERGE function - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimized Query:

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.description, t2.version 
FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 
ON t2.name = t1.name 
 AND t2.description = t1.description  
 AND (t2.version     = t1.version
     OR  (t2.version IS NULL AND t1.version IS NULL))
WHERE t1.ID is NULL
```

Comment: Its better to use [NVL](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php) like this `NVL(t2.version, '-')     = NVL(t1.version, '-')`

Answer (score 6):

NULL value when compare with anything will return FALSE. You will need to use `IS NULL` to handle

```
select t2.name, t2.description, t2.version
from   Table2 as t2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
       ( 
            SELECT *
            FROM   Table1 as t1 
            WHERE  t2.name        = t1.name 
            AND    t2.description = t1.description 
            AND    (
                       t2.version     = t1.version
                   OR  (t2.version IS NULL AND t1.version IS NULL)
                   )
       )
```

Comment: This won't work if i have a null version in table2 and not in table1. See my updated post

Comment: doesn't this query gives your expected result ?

Comment: it doesn't, since Id 5 in table 2 is missing because the version is null

Comment: i tried and it did gives the same expected result that you have posted

Comment: mm weird. Let me test again. My coffee wasnt that strong when i tested i guess lol.

Answer (score 1):

you can use EXCEPT for this problem. 
you can use a common field from two tables and then select your data from that result.

look this following code :

```
SELECT name, description, version FROM Table2
EXCEPT
SELECT name, description, version FROM Table1
```

this code give you data that exist in table2 that not exist in table1.

Comment: I have to compare the Name, title and version, not the ids

Comment: you just need to name your columns. and its works. it consider null values too. please test this code first. and then reply. thanks

Comment: The problem with EXCEPT is that i cannot select more columns than the one specified in my EXCEPT query but NOT EXIST or LEFT JOIN does

Comment: I think you dont know what u want and with my solution you cover it all.

Comment: Luv Knew what i wanted and solved my problem. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply `ISNULL()` function:

```
SELECT t2.name, t2.description, t2.version
FROM Table2 AS t2
WHERE  
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT t1.name, t1.description, t1.version 
                FROM Table1 as t1 
                WHERE t2.name = t1.name 
                  AND t2.description = t1.description  
                  AND ISNULL(t2.version,0) = ISNULL(t1.version,0)
```